# How to use celery as a micro service in django

Tags: python, celery, message-queue, microservices, django-celery

I want to run celery as a micro service in django, so that i can access the same instance of celery from my multiple services instead of creating/opening celery connection in each and every service separately. 
Any suggestions over how can i implement this task.

Thanks in advance.